# How are the Spacex Falcon 9 landing legs actuated?

Tags: spacex

What is the mechanism and what medium is used in the actuators to open the legs of the Falcon 9 First Stage on landing?

Answer (score 7):

The mechanism is a pneumatic cylinder. The cylinder is [actuated](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/330053450261987328/photo/1) by a bottle of [high-pressure helium](http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/space-flight-news/spacexs-falcon-9-to-sport-landing-legs-for-nasa-crs-3-mission-to-iss/).

[image: F9 Landing leg]

Comment: Do you know what sort of fluid is used and how it is pressurised?

Comment: Huh! I'd swear I heard that the legs are actuated by a pneumatic system powered by high-pressure helium... Was there a change?

Comment: The spaceflight101 article you've linked to says so: "During flight, the legs are stowed against the rocket body. (...) Deployment is accomplished by a pneumatic system using high-pressure helium."

Comment: Sorted. It's annoying that the only primary source on this is a photo published on Twitter with a one-line comment. NTRS it ain't.